# Quick Create Onload js not working When i am click on Close as lost button on load of opportunity close quick create from above code is not working

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

```
function OnloadStatus(executionContext){
var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
var revenuetype = formContext.getAttribute("revenuetype").getValue();
var interviewclient = formContext.getAttribute("interviewclient").getValue();
var Owner = formContext.getAttribute("ownerid").getValue();
var optystatuscode = formContext.getAttribute("opportunitystatuscode").getValue();
if(formContext !== null){
if((revenuetype === 783130001 || revenuetype === 783130007)) //ClosedLOst
{
if (optystatuscode ===783130012){
formContext.getControl("lossreason").setVisible(true);
formContext.getAttribute("lossreason").setRequiredLevel("required");            
formContext.getControl("interviewclient").setVisible(true);
formContext.getAttribute("interviewclient").setRequiredLevel("required");   
formContext.getControl("description").setVisible(true);
formContext.getAttribute("description").setRequiredLevel("required");
}
}
if (optystatuscode === 783130014) //Duplicate
{
formContext.getAttribute("lossreason").setValue(717910010);
formContext.getAttribute("interviewclient").setValue(717910001);    
formContext.getControl("interviewclient").setVisible(false);
formContext.getControl("clienttointerview").setVisible(false);
formContext.getControl("description").setVisible(false);     
}

if (optystatuscode === 3) //Won
{
formContext.getControl("interviewclient").setVisible(false);
formContext.getControl("lossreason").setVisible(false);
formContext.getControl("description").setVisible(false);

}
}   
}
```

Above code is triggered on OnChange but not from OnLoad. Code perspective there are no errors as code is getting executed successfully from Onchange flow. can any one please help.

Comment: why do you need this code to run on a quick create when it has nothing to do with it?  also, you might be confusing quick create with the modal dialog form you get when closing an opportunity, those are two separate things.